# Insert BLOB image into BLOB column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script, which contain a `BLOB session image`. I want to insert it into the BLOB column.

**my wrong code**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$userName = "John";
$aVatar = $_SESSION['userImage']; //[BLOB] - from MySql BLOB image
$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `avatar`) VALUES ('$userName', '$aVatar')";
if($conn->query($query) == TRUE){
    echo "Done!";
}
?>
```

When i post this, it show's very long strings into my page! and the message bellow all:
[image]

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: Sir, when i post this, it show's very long strings into my page! and the message bellow all, say: ... your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[SYMBOL]' at line 1.

Comment: Add the error message to your question

Comment: Sir, please see it

Comment: If you use prepared Statements your problem will be solved

Comment: I forget the ' quotes, now please see it again.

Comment: Your string contains also quotes. As i told you many times, use prepared statements

Comment: shouldn't you use `add_slashes()` or `mysql_escape_string()`

Comment: Abhishek Keshri, nothing happening, no error and no inserted!
@Nick, the same problem appear.

Comment: what is the datatype of column avatar ? and can you show the output of $aVatar

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri I checked the error say: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\0�\0\0\'\0\0\0Ç�\0\0 \0IDATx���y�fw' at line 1

Comment: try this ```$aVatar =addslashes( $_SESSION['userImage']); ```

Comment: could you please check by yourself into my PC by using team viewer?

Comment: @Aso edited the answer. try that

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri still I have problem with this, could you please remote my PC by using `Team Viewer` - My ID: 489 638 077 and My Password is: 3677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that, if the variable `$_SESSION['userImage']` contains any `'`, the query would not be valid. So you should use `mysql_escape_string()` to sanitize it:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `avatar`) VALUES ('$userName', '" . mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['userImage']) . "')";
```

You can also use `addslashes()` while assigning the blob variable to solve this:

```
$aVatar = addslashes($_SESSION['userImage']);
```

Comment: You should not use mysql_escape_string, since it's deprecated.